# jQuery AJAX vs PHP in HTML attribute

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, function

If I want to do some PHP on an event(e.g. onchange) should I use jQuery ajax like:

```
$("#elm").on("change", function(){
    //ajax code
}
```

, should I use the PHP in the HTML attribute like:

```
<element onchange="<?php //stuff to do ?>"></element>
```

Comment: listeners all the way. kill the use of html on events

Comment: php executes first on the server, then js executes second on the client. If you have some php you want to execute after the page has loaded, you'll need to use ajax.

Comment: what do really want to do? insert an element from database or...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be conflating two different issues.

### JS bound events vs intrinsic event attributes.

Bind your event handlers with JS. 
Follow the principles of [Progressive Enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) and [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

### Ajax vs Putting PHP in a JS function

If you put PHP in a JS function then it will run when the PHP outputs the JS function to the browser, **not** when the JS function is called.

If you want to run PHP in response to an event, then you have to make an HTTP request to the server to run the PHP.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert content from the load of page and leave it static, you should use only PHP.

If you want to insert content *dynamically* (changing with users interactions) you should use AJAX.

I can't found out what are you trying to achieve with your example, so not very sure what you should do there.

Answer (score 0):

taking your code it would give this :

```
$("#elm").on("change", function(){
    //ajax code

$.get('url', {data:'tosend'}, function(data){

    // here you have the response of the php script in the data object 
    // it can be json for exemple

});

}
```

You must realise two things, your php code will be render when the page is loaded in the

`browser so the second code you gave us`

means that your "onchange" event is already present in your page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to request something (data, html, etc) to server from a loaded page, then do an ajax.
In that case below code is correct.

```
$("#elm").on("change", function(){
    //ajax code
}
```

You cannot execute a piece of php code from client side. But you can assign values from php to javascript and then do operations on client side.